# Calculation using two subsets of variable column in long data frame with R Reshape

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe that has two sets of data that I need to multiply for a calculation. A simple version would be

```
sample = data.frame(apples=c(10,20,25,30,40,NA,NA,15))
sample$oranges = c(25,60,90,86,10,67,45,10)
sample$oats = c(65,75,85,95,105,115,125,135)
sample$eggs = c(23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16)
sample$consumer =c('john','mark','luke','paul','peter','thomas','matthew','brian')
sample$mealtime = c('breakfast','lunch','lunch','snack','lunch','breakfast','snack','dinner')

s1 = melt(sample,id.vars=c(5,6),measure.vars=c(1:4))
```

and what I'm trying to do is something along the lines of

```
s2 = dcast(s1, mealtime ~ ., function(x) (x[variable == 'oranges'] * x[variable =='apples'])/sum(x[variable == 'apples'])
```

In practice its a much longer data.frame and a more elaborate calculation but the principle should be the same. Thanks -- first post to SO so apologies for any errors.

The output would be a data frame that has mealtimes as the Id var and the apple weighted average of the orange data as the values for each mealtime.

Something along the lines of

```
    Group.1         x
1 breakfast  1.785714
2    dinner  1.071429
3     lunch 27.500000
4     snack 18.428571
```

This was calculated using

```
sample$wa = sample$oranges*sample$apples/sum(sample$apples)
aggregate(sample$wa,by=list(sample$mealtime),sum,na.rm=T)
```

which feels off mathematically but was meant to be a quick kludgy approximation.

Comment: Since your code is failing, can you describe the expected output?

Comment: Can you add in your question *how* you calculated "x" in the provided output.

Comment: Thanks for everyones patience with the iterative process of asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much better task for plyr than it is for reshape.

```
library(plyr)
s1<-ddply(sample,.(mealtime), function(x) {return(sum(x$apples,x$oranges))})
```

And now you have clarified the output:

```
ddply(sample,.(mealtime), summarize,
      wavg.oranges = sum(apples * oranges, na.rm=TRUE) / sum(apples, na.rm=TRUE))
#    mealtime wavg.oranges
# 1 breakfast     25.00000
# 2    dinner     10.00000
# 3     lunch     45.29412
# 4     snack     86.00000
```

Comment: @flodel, I think I'm going to have to track down some of your other answers to upvote to give you some credit here.

Comment: Thanks @flodel. I'm attaching a corollary link to another question I found while researching this and before seeing your response. It follows the same approach and uses dataframes quite cleverly to add additional columns. Mainly for the sake of completeness in case anyone else comes across this looking for the same thing. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277326/group-by-in-r-ddply-with-weighted-mean)