# How to plot weighted means on a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

After searching for a solution and fiddling, I am reaching out for help in my attempt to display weighted means on a boxplot (I have tried to cross-post this to the ggplot2 mailing list as well).

I provide a toy example below.

```
#data

value <- c(5, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 10, 6, 7, 10)
category <- c("one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two",
              "three", "three", "three","three")
weight <- c(1, 1.2, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.5, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 1.5)
df <- data.frame(value, category, weight)

#unweighted means by category
ddply(df, .(category), summarize, mean=round(mean(value, na.rm=TRUE), 2))

  category mean
1      one 6.67
2    three 8.25
3      two 7.33

#weighted means by category
ddply(df, .(category), summarize, 
          wmean=round(wtd.mean(value, weight, na.rm=TRUE), 2))

  category wmean
1      one  7.00
2    three  8.08
3      two  7.26

#unweighted means added to boxplot (which works fine)
ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = value, weight = weight)) + 
   geom_boxplot(width=0.6,  colour = I("#3366FF")) + 
   stat_summary( fun.y ="mean", geom ="point", shape = 23, 
                 size = 3, fill ="white")
```

My question is, how can I display weighted means on the boxplot instead of unweighted means?

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers: the line in the box plot is the median and the geom_point can be configured to present the mean or weighted mean as shown in the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save weighted means as new data frame and then use it to plot `geom_point()`. Argument `inherit.aes=FALSE` will ensure that points are plotted without inheriting information provided in `ggplot()` call.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
df.wm<-ddply(df, .(category), summarize, 
             wmean=round(wtd.mean(value, weight, na.rm=TRUE), 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = value, weight = weight)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.6,  colour = I("#3366FF")) + 
  geom_point(data=df.wm,aes(x=category,y=wmean),shape = 23, 
             size = 3, fill ="white",inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: That was just what the doctor ordered.  Thank you so much! This was very helpful.

Comment: For some reason with this code I got an error, but the code on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277326/group-by-in-r-ddply-with-weighted-mean) worked.