# weighted box plot unknown error

Tags: r

My question is with regards to creating a weighted box plot using **ENmisc** library.  I have a dataframe and I want to plot the boxplot based on two different categories (both type chr).

The error given is `## Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` from the line `wtd.boxplot(df2J$mean_P32 ~ df2J$mode_Litho,weights=df2J$length)`.  I've attached a log of the portion of code in question below which shows the values of each data type as well as that there is not any data missing.  The last line produces a boxplot similar to the one I would expect from the line above.

Unfortunately I don't know how to recreate this error with a general example so I  haven't provided code that can be run.

If anyone could shed some light on this error it would be much appreciated.

Other Info:

- The plots work if I use the base package boxplot function.
- There are other ways I could create weighted boxplots if needed such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204213/how-to-plot-weighted-means-on-a-boxplot) but I really don't see any reason this shouldn't work.
- [wtd.boxplot](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ENmisc/docs/wtd.boxplot) function
- [ENmisc](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/ENmisc/ENmisc.pdf) library
- I'm not sure why this doesn't  show up in the Knitr ourput but The error that shows up in the R console is `Error in if (any(out[nna])) stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(x[!out], na.rm = TRUE) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

[image]

Comment: Downvoted for posting pictures.

Comment: The reason I posted it as a picture was it couldn't be run due to a large data set (8mb) and I couldn't recreate it with generic data.  I thought the image of the output did a good job of showing what I tried and the outputs provided by R.

Comment: The graphic was not my complaint (and df2 couldn't be 8MB if it's only got 248 obs). If you posted (as text)  output of `head(df2 , 20)`, we would have something to work with.

Comment: That's a good point I didn't think of re exporting the data set a after it had been subsetted and summarized.  I will post some data when I am back at my computer tomorrow.  Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it happens because (I think) you have only 1 member for one of your groups. Check it.